# Where is Accord.NET AdaBoost Decide method?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I'm trying to use Accord.NET library for objects classification, but I failed to find any suitable examples and documentation is not enough to understand the process. My current code is

```
Predictor = new Boost<DecisionStump>();
AdaBoost<DecisionStump> Algo = new AdaBoost<DecisionStump>(Predictor, new ModelConstructor<DecisionStump>((double[] weights) => new DecisionStump(10)));
Algo.Run(inputs, outputs);
```

This code works well, but i want to use Decide method like other classifiers in accord.net, how can i do it?

Comment: Hi @HamidEbr, thanks a lot for the question! Do you think you could please open an issue in the project's issue tracker? It seems that the Adaboost had been left behind when most of the existing classifiers were upgraded to the .Decide() API last year!

Comment: @Cesar Thanks, Here it is: https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/843

Comment: @Cesar I get accord.net source code and find  Creation property that uses like var model = Algo.Creation(double[] weights);. It seemed model.Compute(double[] inputs) works like Decide method! But i don`t know about weights in Creation method!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Special Thanks to dear [Cesar](https://github.com/cesarsouza)

https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/843